# Entering SQL Server without password

Tags: c#, sql-server

[image]

The above output is generated from the following code:

```
using System.Windows.Forms;
using Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo;

public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       DataTable dataTable = SmoApplication.EnumAvailableSqlServers(true);
       listBox1.ValueMember = "Name";
       listBox1.DataSource = dataTable;
    }

    private void listBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        listBox2.Items.Clear();
        if (listBox1.SelectedIndex != -1)
        {
            string serverName = listBox1.SelectedValue.ToString();
            Server server = new Server(serverName);
            try
            {
                foreach (Database database in server.Databases)
                {
                    listBox2.Items.Add(database.Name);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                string exception = ex.Message;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This is strange to me.

How is this code being able to enter the SQL Server without asking for username and password?

Comment: `SmoApplication.EnumAvailableSqlServers` probably does it, it either has the connection string in code, or in a config file.

Answer (score 3):

SMO defaults to Windows authentication so your current Windows credentials are used to connect.